# While creating envelope using rest api, sometimes getting an expected response from Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

When creating an envelope using rest api, usually api returns the envelopeId and other information. Sometimes though, I am getting only a {status=processing} response.

As this is randomly seen response, difficult to pin point whats causing it

Trying to see if there is any tracking information which can be used to correlate the request for which the envelopeId (once returned from webhook) can be associated with

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the asynchronous property in your createEnvelope call? That is what would cause the response to return with "status":"processing". More information on asynchronous sending and how to handle the response is available [here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-sending-envelopes-asynchronously)